# How to get a Google API token

Tags: token, oauth-2.0

I need to get the Google validation token to use with Google APIs, but my code does not work.

```
$client_id = '495225261106.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = urlencode('MY_SECRET_CDE');
$redirect_uri = urlencode('http://MYPAGE.net/test.php');
//$grant_type = urlencode('authorization_code'); //it does not work either.
$grant_type = 'authorization_code';

$post_string = "code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp6&client_id={$client_id}&client_secret={$client_secret}&redirect_uri={$redirect_uri}&grant_type={$grant_type}";

//echo_key_value('post_string',$post_string);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);   // Execute the HTTP command
$errmsg = curl_error($ch); 

if($errmsg) echo $errmsg;
```

The output is:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this in javascript but running into the same error.  I've tried using curl from the command line and still no luck.  I've followed the instructions on [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html) to a T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it easier to use Google APIs, especially OAuth stuff, via one of the official client libraries.

Here's a link to the PHP one: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

And a link to the docs on OAuth 2.0 with the library (with some great example code): http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2

Comment: I have the very same problem, invalid grant, I'm posting the data with a browser for debugging purposes. Using their library does not explain why the error appears

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have to put " curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); " before using postfields? Mine is working and except that and I didn't used urlencode on my secret, it's the same

Answer (score 0):

## Setup Instructions

- Go to the Google Developers Console
  https://console.developers.google.com/project Select your project or
  create a new one (and then select it)
- Enable the API for your
  project In the sidebar on the left, expand APIs & auth > APIs Search
  for "drive" Click on "Drive API" click the blue "Enable API" button
- Create a service account for your project In the sidebar on the left,
  expand APIs & auth > Credentials Click blue "Add credentials" button
- Select the "Service account" option
- Select "Furnish a new private
  key" checkbox Select the "JSON" key type option
- Click blue "Create"
  button your JSON key file is generated and downloaded to your machine
  (it is the only copy!)
- open the json file and save your private key to a file called rsa

> note your service account's email address
> (also available in the JSON key file) Share the doc (or docs) with
> your service account using the email noted above

based on information from ( a fantastic doc )
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority

for a list of possible API scopes set
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#sheetsv4

for a purely bash based solution

```
#!/bin/bash

client_email='your client email'
scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'

jwt1=`echo -n '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}' | openssl base64 -e`

exp=$(($(date +%s)+3600))
iat=$(date +%s)

jwt2=`echo -n '{\
"iss":"'"$client_email"'",\
"scope":"'"$scope"'",\
"aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",\
"exp":'$exp',\
"iat":'$iat'}' | openssl base64 -e`

jwt3=`echo -n "$jwt1.$jwt2" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-'`

jwt4=`echo -n "$jwt3" | openssl sha -sha256 -sign rsa | openssl base64 -e`

jwt5=`echo -n "$jwt4" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-'`

echo $jwt3
echo $jwt5

curl -H -vvv "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" -d \
"grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=$jwt3.$jwt5"
```

for a javascript nodejs based solution see

https://gist.github.com/cloverbox/5ce51a1d8889da9045c5b128a3a2502f